# Using the sum of squares formula to solve more complex sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

I'm studying integration and trying to figure out how to use the sum of squares formula to solve more complicated sums.

For example: knowing that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n (n+1) (2 n+1)}{6}$$

how can we simplify

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i/n)^2$$

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_i c\,a_i=c \sum_i a_i$ whenever $c$ is a constant (meaning not dependent on the index $i$) So you can pull $n^2$ out of the sum and use the formula you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key  here is what anon wrote in his comment. It's helpful to expand out the terms of the sum: 
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^n (i/n)^2 & = & \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^2}{n^2}  \\
&=& \frac{1^2}{n^2} +  \frac{2^2}{n^2} + \dots + \frac{n^2}{n^2} \\
&=& \Big( \frac{{1^2} + {2^2} + \dots + {n^2}} {n^2} \Big) \\
& = & \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \\
& = & \frac{1}{n^2}  \frac{n (n+1) (2 n+1)}{6}
\end{eqnarray} $$